# grgit: Checkout a remote branch

Tags: git, gradle, android-gradle-plugin, build.gradle, gradle-plugin

I am trying to checkout a remote branch from git using grdale grgit. This is my code

```
def gitRepo = Grgit.open(dir: '.')
task checkoutBranch(){
    doLast {
        gitRepo.checkout(branch: 'remoteTestBranch', createBranch: false);

    } 
}
```

It fails with the error "Problem checking out" . This works if I already have a local branch called "remoteTestBranch"

But when I do

```
git checkout remoteTestBranch
```

from the command line , it works saying

```
"Branch remoteTestBranch set up to track remote branch remoteTestBranch from origin.
Switched to a new branch 'remoteTestBranch'"
```

But the gradle script doesn't work. What am I doing wrong ?

Comment: @Abhik- How did you setup credentials using grgit ?

Answer (score 2):

The following code works for me, please try it:

```
if(gitRepo.branch.list().find { it.name == 'remoteTestBranch' })
  gitRepo.checkout(branch: 'remoteTestBranch')
else
  gitRepo.checkout(branch: 'remoteTestBranch', startPoint: 'origin/remoteTestBranch', createBranch: true)
```

Comment: @akhilkhl- How to setup credentials using grgit ?